# A minimizing property of the Sphere?

Tags: maxima-minima, average, spheres, minimal-surfaces

From the wiki “Sphere” entry:
  “The sphere has the smallest surface area of all surfaces that enclose
a given volume, and it encloses the largest volume among all closed
surfaces with a given surface area.”

Does this statement, particularly the latter part, imply that of all possible configurations of the same volume V, the sphere also maximizes the  minimum-distance from any point inside the sphere to the sphere’s surface?
(If so, I’m assuming this would only apply to genus-0 objects.)